# Celery Flower-Monitor many celery workers in one Flower dashboard

Tags: redis, vagrant, celery, monitoring, flower

I have many workers running on different EC2 instances and one common Redis [Elasticache] instance they use as broker.

I have set up Flower inside Vagrant [along with celery and redis] and I want to monitor all the remote workers with it.

*Note: Celery+Redis+Flower play along fine with local worker.I send tasks to the worker, stored in Redis and are shown in Flower.*

I have created a tunnel for the remote Redis port 6379 to localhost 6379 and I can access it via Redis Desktop Manager.

Then, inside Vagrant I run `celery flower --broker=redis://10.0.2.2:6379/` so I use the tunneled Redis db via the host OS.

The Flower server starts but it shows up empty.

As I understand it cannot find a worker to monitor.

How am I going to provide it though?

This is the flower's output
[image]

Comment: Set the project name `celery -A proj --broker=redis://10.0.2.2:6379/ `

Comment: '-A proj' is going to be referring to which of the many different remote workers ? I tested it and monitors only the local worker inside Vagrant [which I have only to test things]. As I understand it, inside Vagrant there will be no worker for Flower to attach to. Only Flower that is going to monitor the remote workers. Is it possible?

Comment: I think it is possible. Try with command `inspect ping` to check worker connect to the broker or not and also enable `debug` mode to find out the root cause.